# Couldn't install Ubunutu 19.10 on Medion P15647 - black screen after grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

I'd like to install Ubunutu 19.10 on my new laptop but installation doesn't work properly.
With normal or normal safe boot options, boot ends in a black screen after grub. With the options "acpi=off nolapic nomodeset" there is an error "unable to find a medium containing a live file system". I disabled secure boot in the BIOS options. I tried install with USB and DVD (with external drive).

Has anybody an idea what to try next?

Thank you

Information about the laptop:
https://www.medion.com/de/shop/p/multimedia-notebooks-medion-akoya-p15647-intel-core-i7-10510u-windows-10-home-39-5-cm-15-6-fhd-display-mx250-256-gb-ssd-1-5-tb-hdd-16-gb-ram-notebook-30027578A1 (german)

Update:
I tried now to install Debian. With boot flag acpi=off it worked mostly. But grub couldn't be installed and it just starts manually in text mode (also with acpi=off).

Comment: I used the check function in grub - there where no errors (on macbook pro 2012). Also I installed ubuntu with this image and usb stick on an ASUS X55A and boot the usb stick in live mode on a macbook pro 2012 - also with no errors.

Comment: I checked the iso now with Linux Subsystem for Windows. The image is ok.

Comment: I think the hardware/drivers cause the problems, but I don't know who to identify/fix them.

Comment: Yesterday I successfully installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a medion notebook (intel-core-i5-10210, mx250 nvidia gc, pch 400 and uefi are the same for us, and that's important). If you are interested in my solution, leave a comment and I will write a post. btw: forget about the medion forum, the posts are outdated and and some solutions even funny. I also installed dde desktop (as a try) form source. Really nice!!!